# "Все побежали () и я побежал"

Tags: пунктуация

Знаменитая фраза из "Джентльменов удачи" — "Все побежали () и я побежал". По логике после слова "побежали" нужна запятая, но интонационно — скорее тире. А как правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, оба варианта будут верны. Однако предпочтительнее тире, т.к. в данном случае оно отражает здесь причинно-следственную связь.

Comment: Согласен, тире будет предпочтительнее.

Comment: причинно-следственная связь - это для бессоюзного предложения,            а здесь - неожиданное присоединение.